# Thumbnails cover fixed navigation bar when hovered over

Tags: jquery, navigation, hover, css-position

I've applied a grayscale to color hover effect on my gallery thumbnails on my site, and they seem to be working fine.  HOWEVER, they are interfearing with the fixed navigation bar at the top.

For example, if you scroll down to see the lower "graphic design" thumbnails & want to use the navigation bar to move on to the "art" section, it's impossible because the colored hover thumbnail gets in the way! Does anyone happen to know a solution to this problem?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to use some css styles for your work
Add z-index values to the navigation bar higher than z-index of your thumbnails and the container's div as well

Comment: I had the z-index for just the .thumbnail tag, but not for the wrapper and content containers — works like a charm now!  Thank you so much!